# Animated gif file not working in IE7

Tags: animated-gif

I'm learning Ajax from Sams Teach Yourself Ajax,Javascript and Php All in One
and testing an example which diplays the server time OK but does not show a busy gif image.
In fact all I get is the red cross box where the file should be
Windows Picture and Fax Viewer displays the moving gif file OK so what am I doing wrong?
I have no prior knowledge of using gif files

Comment: First, you can put the image inside the page (somewhere else), non-hidden, and see if you see the image animated.  And then, do you actually redirect to a different page when you show the GIF?  I remotely remember long time ago that if you show the animated GIF and redirect to a different page right away, then the GIF won't animate on IE.  do you want to paste some sample code or show us your link so we can check what's the case?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the red cross box and select Properties. The subsequent window will show you where IE is looking for the file. In all possibility, the location may not be correct. Must be a problem with the way you are using relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

Properties shows "Type not available" (but file name is "anim.gif")
File location is OK

Comment: Does the file have a proper extension? I dont think it should say type not available.
If you can share some code it might be useful.

Comment: Alan, you are not supposed to add a response to an answer as another answer. Just add a comment... like this.

Comment: Can you share the location? If it just says anim.gif then it might be a relative path problem.